# How to change Pandoc's PDF conversion style?

Tags: pdf, pandoc, output, parameters

In the past I could get Latex and Markdown files converted to PDF with Pandoc and I could get the output in different PDF styles. Now I forgot how I did it, and I can just get the default style.

The command I am using is:

`pandoc ./text.md --from markdown -o text.pdf --to pdf`

I think I added another parameter to specify futher details about the PDF output, but I cannot recall what it was. I am sure I did not use a custom template.

On the documentation I could not find any information in this regard.

Comment: By style do you mean the document class?

Comment: @Fran, I mean the look of the final document, and not its contents. Things like fonts, links' color, tables' look, etc. It is likely I used the wrong term...

Comment: You are asking actually for big piece of the [Pandoc User Guide](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html). Many variables can be used to change the look, trough options of the pandoc commnad, via a custom template or with a YALM header. BTW, with any of these approaches I  would start by setting the `documentclass` variable.

Comment: There are also predefined templates, like [eisvogel](https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template), out there... Here is a list: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/User-contributed-templates